# Json deserialization is not supportted

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui-sortable, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm having trouble deserializing an array in .NET MVC5, any help would be appreciated.

```
JsonList psl = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<JsonList>(id);
```

My objects

```
[Serializable]
public class JsonList
{
    public object[] id { get; set; }
    public List<children> children { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
public class children
{
    public List<object> id { get; set; }
}
```

Json Array

```
 "[
   {\"id\":20,\"children\":[]},{\"id\":21,\"children\":[{\"id\":23},
        {\"id\":22},   {\"id\":24},
   {\"id\":26}]},{\"id\":27,\"children\":[{\"id\":56},{\"id\":57},
        {\"id\":51},{\"id\":50},
   {\"id\":55},{\"id\":52},{\"id\":65},{\"id\":53}]},
        {\"id\":28,\"children\":[{\"id\":29},
   {\"id\":30},{\"id\":32},{\"id\":79}]},
       {\"id\":33,\"children\":[{\"id\":34},{\"id\":35},
   {\"id\":39}]},{\"id\":40,\"children\":[{\"id\":41},{\"id\":42},
           {\"id\":43},{\"id\":44},
   {\"id\":75}]},{\"id\":45,\"children\":[{\"id\":47},
           {\"id\":82},{\"id\":49}]}
]"
```

Jquery Sortable

```
var UINestable=function(){
var updateOutput=function(e){
    var list = e.length ? e : $(e.target), output = list.data('output');
    var dataid = window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize'));
    if (window.JSON) {
        alert(dataid);
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Admin/Menuler/MenuSiralama',
                data: "{id:'" + dataid + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(result) {
                },
                error: function() {
                }
            }
        );
    }       
    else{console.log('JSON browser support required for this demo.');}
};
return{init:function(){
      $('#nestable_list_1').nestable({group:2})
               .on('change',updateOutput);}};
}();
```

Comment: Are you using json.net library?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[Serializable]
public class JsonList
{
    public object[] id { get; set; }
    public children children { get; set; }
}
```

You need not to consider children property as List according to your JSON data sample you try to POST.

Either children property should be of type of children class (you declared it as a list of children class), or support collection of children class in your JSON structure.